# rails Select Form Tag - How to add a default "All" option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following which creates a select box:

```
<%=select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name")%>
```

This creates an item for each person, problem is I would like a "All People" value 0, option added and selected by default on load?

does the select_tag in rails 3 support this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a multiple_select_tag might be more appropriate instead of an all?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply include a `:include_blank => 'All People'` option in your `select_tag`:

```
<%= select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name"), :include_blank => 'All People' %>
```

Comment: The `:include_blank => "All people"` generates the following code: `<option value></option>`. Perhaps they've changed the syntax or something?

Comment: include_blank now takes a true/false value. To add a default option, :prompt => 'Select One' is the way to go. It also needs to go within the options hash. in all,  
`<%= select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name"), { :prompt => 'All People' } %>`